# Mule DB data retrieval into chunks

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio, mule-el

We are trying to extract approx. 40 GB data from database and want to generate multiple csv files. We used mule DB connector in streaming fashion, which is returning 'ResultSetIterator'

Q1) How to convert this `ResultSetIterator` to arraylist? or any readable format which we can use further to generate files

Q2) We tried using For-Each component to split this data in chunks, its working for limited set of data and for huge data giving `SerializationException`

In below input snippet we are making chunks of data using for-each and providing it to batch process for multiple files

```
  <batch:job name="testBatchWithDBOutside">
        <batch:input>
            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </batch:input>
        <batch:process-records>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
                <batch:commit size="10" doc:name="Batch Commit">
                    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
                    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\output" outputPattern="#[message.id].txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
                </batch:commit>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
    </batch:job>
    <flow name="testBatchWithDBOutsideFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" streaming="true" fetchSize="10" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from classicmodels]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
        <foreach batchSize="5" doc:name="For Each">
            <batch:execute name="testBatchWithDBOutside" doc:name="testBatchWithDBOutside"/>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1. You don't want to convert the Iterator to a List, as this will defeat the purpose of streaming from the DB connector and load all records into memory. Mule handles Iterators and Lists in the same way anyway.

Q2. The batch module implies a for-each operation. The output of batch:input needs to be a List or an Iterator. You should be able to simplify this

```
<batch:job name="testBatch">
    <batch:input>
        <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" streaming="true" fetchSize="10" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from classicmodels]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
    </batch:input>
    <batch:process-records>
        <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
            <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\output" outputPattern="#[message.id].txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:process-records>
</batch:job>
```

You will also need to replace the object-to-string-transformer with a component that converts a database record (the payload at this point will be a map where the key is the column name, and the value is the record value) into a csv line.

You can find a decent example in the Mule blog here: https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/batch-module-reloaded/

Another option would be to remove the batch processor and use DataWeave to generate csv output and stream it to the file. This might be helpful: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-streaming

Dataweave will call next on the ResultSetIterator as it processes each record, and that Iterator will handle selecting chunks of records from the underlying database, so there is no queueing in between steps, or loading the full dataset into memory.

```
<flow name="batchtestFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/batch" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" streaming="true" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from Employees]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
            %input payload application/java
            %output application/csv streaming=true, header=true, quoteValues=true
            ---
            payload map ((e, i) -> {
                surname: e.SURNAME,
                firstname: e.FIRST_NAME
            })]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:/tmp" outputPattern="testbatchfile.csv" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: I Agree this simple batch process will work for a smaller set of data, but Input Phase of Batch process will load entire data to queue store of runtime, which results into degraded performance.So we are passing chunks to Batch process from different process

Comment: I was able to create a quick test of your process with 30,000 records and had no problems. If this doesn't work for you, I suggest using Dataweave to generate the CSV, rather than using the batch process. I will update my answer with a Dataweave example.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use OutputHander. Make sure you have streaming turned on and then use a script component, for instance select groovy and handle each row one at a time like so:

```
// script.groovy
return {evt, out ->

 payload.each { row ->
  out << row.SOMECOLUMN....  }

} as OutputHandler
```

And the component in your xml

```
    <scripting:transformer returnClass="TODO" doc:name="ScriptComponent">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy" file="script.groovy" />
    </scripting:transformer>
```

If you want to return some output. However if you want to write to a file in your case you wouldn't use the variable `out` but instead write to your files.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple and quickest way as below:

Here DB connector is in streaming mode, and For-Each is splitting the records in given Batch Size

```
<flow name="testFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <composite-source doc:name="Composite Source">
            <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="test" cronExpression="0 48 13 1/1 * ? *" repeatInterval="0" connector-ref="Quartz" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
                <quartz:event-generator-job/>
            </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
            <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/hit" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        </composite-source>
        <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" streaming="true" fetchSize="10000" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM tblName]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
         <foreach batchSize="10000" doc:name="For Each">

                    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
                                           <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
                   %output application/csv
                   ---
                   payload map {
                    field1:$.InterfaceId,
                    field2:$.Component

                   }]]></dw:set-payload>
                    </dw:transform-message>
               <file:outbound-endpoint path="F:\output" outputPattern="#[message.id].csv" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        </foreach>
        <set-payload value="*** Success ***" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

    </flow>
```